# using hibernate Criteria.uniqueResult() when there are several results

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a table USERS with names and creation dates, and an api function

```
T read(Criterion... criteria)
```

that searches by criterions that i cant change.

My problem is that the function returns crit.uniqueResult() but sometimes the criteria gives many names (in which case i want only the name with the latest date).
how can i add a criterion to make sure only the latest name is returned?

```
public T read(Criterion... criteria){
  Criteria crit = getSession(false).createCriteria(this.type);
  for (Criterion c : criteria) 
  {
    crit.add(c);
  }
  T entity = (T)crit.uniqueResult();
  return entity;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you can have a read method that returned the top result, a method that returns a `List<T>` and one that you pass in the number of results to return.

For example you could use then use max results setting

```
criteria.setMaxResults(1);
List<T> results = criteria.list();
return results.get(0);
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setMaxResults%28int%29

Comment: Yes, but the results would need to be ordered by date (descending)

Comment: i need to use the infastructure read(Criterion... criteria) function , so i can only work with criterions, I dont have access to the criteria in the function